# actions on google userStorage only during session

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

For certain users, the actions on google userStorage object lives only during sessions. When the next launch request comes, it disappears (it's not in the incoming json). I recreate it with a new user id - everything is fine during the session, then I lose the stored state because I have to generate a new user id. For most of the users it works fine.

Am I missing something in the device setup? Voice identification? We are using DialogFlow but I don't think it is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Have those users enabled the **Web & Activity setting** and the **include chrome history setting** in the [activity center](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols)?
If these settings are not enabled the user storage won't persist to the next conversation and anything that you save will be lost.

Comment: Thank you, Jordi! You are a life saver! This was it!

Comment: Glad I could help!