# Why is persistent storage not working in my google action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to store a UserId across sessions, following the reference found here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/save-data

Here is my implementation in code:

```
'use strict';

const { dialogflow } = require("actions-on-google");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {

  conv.user.storage.userId = "bananas";
  console.log("Logging the conversation object... ");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(conv));
  conv.close("Goodbye! ");
});

exports.yourAction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When I invoke the action via my Google home hub, it will set my user storage data correctly:

```
    "user": {
    "raw": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "lastSeen": "2020-02-12T14:28:49Z",
        "userVerificationStatus": "VERIFIED"
    },
    "storage": {
        "userId": "bananas"
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "verification": "VERIFIED",
    "permissions": [],
    "last": {
        "seen": "2020-02-12T14:28:49.000Z"
    },
    "name": {},
    "entitlements": [],
    "access": {},
    "profile": {}
},
```

However, when i comment out the storage assignment in the code, and re-invoke the action, the contents of the user storage are no longer present:

```
"user": {
    "raw": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "lastSeen": "2020-02-12T14:31:30Z",
        "userVerificationStatus": "VERIFIED"
    },
    "storage": {},
    "locale": "en-US",
    "verification": "VERIFIED",
    "permissions": [],
    "last": {
        "seen": "2020-02-12T14:31:30.000Z"
    },
    "name": {},
    "entitlements": [],
    "access": {},
    "profile": {}
},
```

I can see that my verification is "VERIFIED", so it can't be that issue. I notice in this docs that the userStorage will clear if:

- Voice match is set up and there is no match.
- The user disabled personal data.

So maybe it's one of these - however I'm not sure where I can check!

Comment: Is this a GSuite account?

Comment: I've never used this service before! My domain for this account is @gmail.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [actions on google userStorage only during session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208082/actions-on-google-userstorage-only-during-session)

Comment: That was it thanks! Do you know if there is a way we can detect this during the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I did not have my chrome history setting enabled! This thread goes into more detail:
[actions on google userStorage only during session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58208082/actions-on-google-userstorage-only-during-session/58216779#58216779)